# Determine which functions belong to cubic spline

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been struggling to do this question, from my understanding to determine an equation $f(x)$ belongs to a cubic spline, I am required to differentiate that equation twice. Then I need to solve all three equation: $f(x)$, $f'(x)$, and $f''(x)$ for $x$, and all of them have to be of the same answer, is this correct?

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

> Let $X = [—2, —1,0,1,2]$. Determine which of the following functions belong to the cubic spline $S_x$. Justify your answer:
>   $f_{1}(x)=\sin(x) - x$
>   $f_{2}(x)= |x|^3-|x-0.5|^3$
>   $f_{3}(x)= |x+1|^3$
>   $f_{4}(x)= 1$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Comment: @Saad My apology. I have edited the question, thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of a cubic spline that was given ? (Obviously, $f_1$ is not.)

Comment: no, all of them cannot give the same answer : otherwise you could express a sine function as a polynomial...

Comment: @YvesDaoust (i) f(x), f'(x), and f"(x) are continuous and (ii) f(x) is a cubic polynomial on each interval [xi−1, xi], i = 1, . . . , n.

Comment: So what are you missing ? And what is $X$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust X = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]

Comment: @Srslyshzly: yes, this is in your post. But what does it mean ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust from my understanding, those are the interpolant points? The question I've stated is the complete question, there's no other information left out.